# Python equivalent of Scala Options to avoid NoneType has no attribute error?

Tags: python, nonetype

It's fantastic really that in Python everything could be None, but when you have a object like this:

Person.address.zipcode

If Person or address is None, you'll get 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'

Is there a way to say if Person or address is None, (same goes for zipcode) then just return None?

In Scala you could do

```
Person.flatMap(_.address.flatMap(_.zipcode))
```

and the result would be Option[Zipcode]

Is there an equivalent solution in Python? Other than writing a helper function to catch the exception and return None?

Comment: [There's a proposal for None-aware operators.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) I don't know how much support it has.

Comment: In Python, idiomatically, you would use exception-handling.